# How to use EnableMSDeployAppOffline when doing continuous deployment to azure websites?

Tags: git, msdeploy, azure-web-app-service, app-offline.htm

According to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/30/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum.aspx), it's possible to have MSDeploy automatically drop an App_Offline.htm file when deploying.

Sadly, it doesn't appear to work when using the VSOnline "GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate" build process and deploying to Windows Azure Websites.

Is there any workaround to leverage this feature?  Any other solutions that don't require manually stopping the website prior to the build kicking off?

Answer (score 2):

That setting was primarily used in On-premise servers. On cloud there is an alternate and a better to perform deployments.

Use Deployment Slots. 
References: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/#custom-warm-up-before-swap

There are several articles out there outlining the advantages and features.